# MVC site return Image URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, url

I have an MVC site that has `ONION` architecture.

I am trying to display some images, and my current attempt has me returning a `URL` of an image from an `API` call, and then using this path to retrieve the image in the `HTML`.

However, I am having some trouble establishing what the URL of the image should be, which makes me wonder if it is possible to do this.

Basically, this would be the URL for the API call:

```
http://devServer/api/v1/relevant?Id=187582
```

which would return an object the has an image `URL`

Then, in my `REST` folder, I would create a folder called `Images` that would hold all the images, and then I would expect them to be retrieved by a `URL` such as this:

```
http://devServer/Images/img.png
```

Is this possible, and if so how can I find the URL?

Trying the following returns a `URL` with a `querystring`, which does not seem to be the URL that will return the image:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
//etc...
```

Comment: Why can't you just return `"/Images/img.png"`? then the tag should go to the root of the website `<img src="/Images/img.png" />`

Comment: Although that may work, for my current purpose I need the full URL

Comment: Then you should introduce a setting for the environment (e.g. web.config etc) where you'd store the externally accessible URL. While you could workout where the current request came from, if the website is placed behind a load balancer, this may be `localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I should have used:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
```

Comment: If your app is running behind a reverse proxy, this may return `localhost` no matter what URL was in user's browser.

Comment: @zaitsman +1 for thoroughness, but in this case it will not be

Comment: @zaitsman given your comments, and the fact that the answer above does not return the protocol, I am indeed storing the URL as a global setting - not ideal as it has its own drawbacks, but it will solve my problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this code, if it suits your needs:

```
// Get request object
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
// Generate base application url
var appBaseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));

// Somehow get name of an image (from filesystem, db, etc.)
var imageFileName = "img.png";
// Generate full image url
var imageUrl = string.Format("{0}/Images/{1}", appBaseUrl, imageFileName);
```

Then return that `imageurl` as a property of object or string or whatever your API result will be.

**EDIT:**

To join mine solution and zaitsman's remarks, you could write some little helper for returning image urls:

```
public string GetImageUrl(string baseUrlFromConfig, string imageFileName)
{
    // Get request object
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    // Generate base application url
    var appBaseUrl = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseUrlFromConfig)
        ? baseUrlFromConfig
        : string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));

    // Generate full image url
    var imageUrl = string.Format("{0}/Images/{1}", appBaseUrl, imageFileName);

    return imageUrl;
}
```

In which you would pass in baseUrl from config (if present in config) and imageFileName to append to URL.

Comment: Baaad idea. If your website is placed behind a load balanced the request.Url.Authority will be localhost.

Comment: Would using `request.Url.Host + ":" + request.Url.Port` then be better?

Comment: No. the request.Url will be `new Uri("http://localhost/action/route");`. If you are running behind a reverse proxy and depending on the setup it may not be possible to get the requestor's original URL. In this case you need to store the public URL somewhere (e.g. this is why you need to do it in Exchange/Sharepoint etc).